# Oracle automatically insert record in multirecord block part 2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

My table looks like this:

```
+-------------------+
|Name               |
+-------------------+
|Name1              |
|Name2              |
|Name3              |
|Name4              |
|Name1Jr            |
|Name2Jr            |
|Name4Jr            |
+-------------------+
```

My multirow block looks like:

[image]

What I wanted to know is how can I insert a record that has the same name with Jr after I insert a name. For example, I inserted Name2, it will also insert Name2Jr into the multirow block. Like this:

[image]

***Note:*** I need to get the value of the automatically inserted data from database.

I tried in ***WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE*** trigger(the answer of Sir @Littlefoot on my last question):

```
if :system.trigger_record = 1 and :test.name is null then
    -- do nothing if it is the first record in a form
    null;
else
    duplicate_record;
    if substr(:test.name, -2) = 'Jr' then
        -- you've duplicated a record which already has 'Jr' at the end - don't do it
        :test.name := null;
    else       
        -- concatenate 'Jr' to the duplicated record
        :test.name := :test.name || 'Jr';
    end if;      
end if;
```

And now, what I want is to know if there is a way to do it on ***WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD*** trigger. The problem there is that the **duplicate_record** can't be used in ***WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD*** trigger. How to do it using procedure, function or something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DUPLICATE_RECORD` is a restricted procedure and you can't use it in `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD` trigger (or any other of the same kind).

As you have to navigate to the next record (if you want to copy it), even if you put that *restricted procedure* into another PL/SQL program unit, everything will just *propagate* and - ultimately - raise the same error. So ... you're out of luck.

Even if you wrote a (stored) procedure which would insert that "Jr" row into the database somewhere behind the scene, you'd have to fetch those values to the screen. As `EXECUTE_QUERY` is the way to do it, and as it is (yet another) restricted procedure, that won't work either.

If you planned to clear data block and fill it manually (by using a loop), you'd have to navigate to next (and next, and next) record with `NEXT_RECORD`, and that's again a restricted procedure. Besides, if it was a data block (and yes, it is), you'd actually create *duplicates* for all records once you'd save changes so - either it would fail with unique constraint violation (which is good), or you'd create duplicates (which is worse).

BTW what's wrong with `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE`? What problems do you have when using it?

Comment: The names with Jr that I'm inserting are all coming from a table. I also forgot to say that I'm using LOV for that. Sorry Sir and thank you again for your response.

Comment: Apparently (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901744/create-record-oracle-forms), you found out that WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE *is* the one you should use. No matter how many topics you open, the answer will still be the same. Sooner you accept the fact that restricted procedures can't be used wherever you'd want, sooner you'll move on. I suggest you read about restricted procedures in Forms Help. Hopefully, things will be clearer to you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

What We need is

- a *Data Block* (`BLOCK1`) with

  `Query Data Source Name` is `mytable`,

  and `Number of Records Displayed` set to *more than 1*(let it be *5* as in your case).
- a Text item named as `NAME` same as the column name of the table
  `mytable`, and `Database Item property` set to `Yes`.
- a Push Button with `Number of Records Displayed` set to 1,

  `Keyboard Navigable` and `Mouse Navigate` properties are set to `No`

  and has the following code (inside `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger):

  ```
  commit;
  Query_Block1;
  ```

  Where `Query_Block1` is beneath `Program Units` node with this code :

  ```
  PROCEDURE Query_Block1 IS
  BEGIN
    execute_query;
    last_record;
    down;
  END;
  ```
- A `POST-INSERT` trigger beneath `BLOCK1` node with code :

  ```
     insert into mytable(name) values(:name||'Jr');
  ```
- An `ON-MESSAGE` trigger at the form level with the code (to suppress the messages after *commit*):

  ```
        if    Message_Code in (40400, 40401) then 
          null;
        end if;
  ```
- And `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger with the code :

  ```
        Query_Block1;
  ```