# Create_record oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have a multi-record block and what I wanted is to fire insert record after leaving a record (going up or down).

I tried to put **create_record** in ***WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD*** but it say that its an illegal restricted procedure.

How can I do **create_record** in ***WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD***? Do I need a procedure/timer? Please show me how. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` trigger, *where* using `create_record` built-in is **not restricted** , at that mentioned *multiple-record block level* instead of `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD` in which using is **restricted**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the key-triggers to accomplish this.
So if you make the following triggers:

```
key-down     -> down arrow
key-up       -> up arrow
key-nxtrec   -> next record key
key-prvrec   -> previous record key
```