# HOW TO INSERT RECORD IN DATA BLOCK ON ORACLE FORMS

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have oracle form which contains data block **B_ITEM** which refers database table **master_item**. The   User is entering two items in one *bill* manually in data block and based on certain conditions I need to add freight item in same block **B_ITEM**  automatically.  could you please guide how to insert data in data block.  (Note:I don't want to insert directly in table which it refers)

Step-1 Created a canvas on date block on `B_ITEM` where user can give provide input. Block
 contains field item from `master_item` table.

Step-2 Lets Say, User entered **two items** on canvas which refers `B_ITEM` and click on ok button.

Step-3 So along with two items, one more item should get inserted in block `B_ITEM` and it should display on canvas on **3rd line**.

[image]
In the above image, I have shown example of single item, so once user clicks on OK button 2nd item should get added based on setup table.

`MASTER_FREIGHT_LINK`
ITEM FREIGHT_ITEM
101396306 101396307

So, In canvas freight item should added on second row as soon as user click on `OK` button by entering ITEM-101396306.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what you have, so - let me think aloud.

- there's a table in the database, called MASTER_ITEM
- you created a form whose block B_ITEM is based on the MASTER_ITEM table
- data block contains some items which are, I presume, database items (that belong to the MASTER_ITEM table)
- you enter some data into those items
- based on their values (i.e. *a certain condition*), you'd want to populate FREIGHT_ITEM which resides in the same block, but is not a database item. Is that correct?

If that's so,

- create the FREIGHT_ITEM (there are several ways to do that; a simple one is to use the vertical toolbar's `+` button; or, copy/paste one of existing items and modify its properties)
- create WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger on items that should decide which value should be put into the FREIGHT_ITEM. Put the condition you mentioned into the trigger code and populate FREIGHT_ITEM's value, e.g.

  ```
  if :b_item.item1 > 100 and 
     :b_item.item2 = 'A' 
  then
     :b_item.freight_item := 42;
  end if;
  ```

Now, as you said that you don't want to store that value into the database directly (which means that it is not a database item), you'll have to do it manually, creating additional ON-INSERT and/or PRE-INSERT and/or PRE-UPDATE trigger, which will do that as

```
update master_item i set
  i.freight_item = :b_item.freight_item
  where i.some_id = :b_item.some_id;
```

Comment: Data block does not contain any value.Based on user input in the canvas(which is nothing but data block **B_ITEM**) is going to populate `MASTER_ITEM`.  But along with user input I need to add one more freight item in the same block.  There is no separate freight_item column. Its one more item (business point of view its freight_item i.e. freight charges of that bill)

Comment: OK, so - when you run the form, it is empty. Then user enters a value into some item (you don't input anything "into the canvas"; it is just a *background*) that belongs to B_ITEM data block. Then what? You said that "based on user input" "something" is going to populate a table in the database (table name is MASTER_ITEM). With what values? Moreover, you need to add "freight item in the same block" - what does that mean? You can't just "add" an item (if you meant to create it dynamically) - it has to exist in that block. If possible, describe step-by-step what you're doing.

Comment: Do that (description) by editing the initial message you posted; don't put everything into a comment as it might be difficult to read and follow. Also, attach a form screenshot, it might help.

Comment: Similar question posted, where you have provided some answer.  Could you eloborate?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50854199/oracle-automatically-insert-record-in-multirecord-block-part-2

Comment: I've said everything I meant, based on information I have. It is you who should *elaborate*, not me.

Answer (score 0):

ON-INSERT trigger can be used to override oracle forms insert mechanism. Write in the on-insert trigger the insert statements necessary, which can insert data on any table.